# Word for when you scrunch up your face in frustration

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find the word for when you screw up your face in annoyance, frustration/exasperation or worry. The phrase in which I want to use it is as follows:

> Ryan ____ his face in frustration. He knew he should have never taken his eyes off of her for even a second and now she was missing.

Comment: Would you accept an intransitive verb? "Ryan scowled in frustration."

Comment: There is also [*grimace*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=grimace+meaning), although [*frown*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=frown+meaning) may be more appropriate.

Comment: @Mick I've used grimace in the following sentence, so I can't use it there, and my characters seem to do an awful lot of frowning

Comment: Too much gurning, then. Get rid of it all. "Don’t tell me the moon is shining; show me the glint of light on broken glass." ~ Anton Chekov.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with either **screwed** as in:

```
Ryan screwed his face in frustration
```

[From the Free Dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/screwed) To contort (one's face).

or with **contorted** as in:

```
Ryan contorted his face in frustration
```

[From Google:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+contort&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
to twist or bend out of its normal shape

Comment: And there's "screwed up", as in "he screwed up his face in frustration".  Although this expression probably has been lost to the (probably newer) meaning of "screw up".

Answer (score 0):

Ryan made a moue.
(Here're your other thirteen characters.)
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moue

Answer (score 0):

[***scowl***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scowl)

> To wrinkle or contract the brow as an expression of anger or disapproval

*(thefreedictionary.com)*

> Ryan **scowled** in frustration. He knew he should have never taken his eyes off of her for even a second and now she was missing.

Another possibility would be *frown*.